# Mongodb doesn't insert object to collection with another objects

Tags: java, mongodb, jdbc, persistence

I'm trying to insert an object to collection, that already contains some documents in my `MongoDB`.

```
    Mongo mongo = null;
    try {
        mongo = new Mongo("localhost", 27017);
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    DB db = mongo.getDB("testDB");
    DBCollection collection = db.getCollection("testCollection");
    BasicDBObject document = new BasicDBObject();
    document.put("string", "test");
    document.put("double", new Double(30));
    document.put("date", new Date());
    collection.insert(document);
```

This part of the code doesn't insert anything. Nevertheless when I change the target collection to some non-existing, this collection is created then and all objects are corectly inserted. Inserting objects works fine when I push data in a `json` formate as well. Why I can't insert data as objects then?

Comment: How are you verifying that nothing is inserted into "testCollection" after the call to DBCollection.insert(DBObject)?

Comment: Simply by looking to the DB

Comment: What's in `testCollection` already? Can you show us what it looks like before and after the insert? I don't believe that the code is inserting only when the target collection is empty.

Comment: Cca 150 documents containing _id, some Dates, Strings, Doubles, fields and arrays... Document has usually 14 properties.